# GCP - How to Register to Object Changes with Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Is there a way to use GCP java SDK that does the same as below command?

```
gsutil notification create -t [TOPIC_NAME] -f json gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Didn't find anything in the documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Java client library for GCS supports any [notificationConfigs operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/notifications).  If you need this functionality, consider commenting on [the GitHub issue for it](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1420).

Edit:
Ah, it looks like this was added separately in the [google-cloud-notification client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-notification/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/notification/NotificationInfo.java).

Comment: [@Arkadiy Verman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609797), FYI: someone pointed out to me that this functionality is available, just in a different client under that repository.  I amended my answer with the link.

Comment: thanks @mhouglum I've added example with code https://gist.github.com/poluektik/dd6b5f47b5c90558e983adc2c3208287